# Visualising wordcloud of most frequent terms from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, nlp, word-cloud

I have a subset of a pandas dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({index: [0,1,2]}, {viz_words: ['palace boat painting reel', ['paintings painting gallery'], ['biscuits cake gallery cafe']}

<OUT> df
index       viz_words
0           palace boat painting reel
1           paintings painting gallery
2           biscuits cake gallery cafe
```

I am trying to take all words from `viz_words` column and create a wordcloud that visualises higher-frequency terms larger as larger and smaller-frequency terms smaller.

I have this so far, but the issue is that it is only visualising the "common" terms among `viz_words` which means it misses out on a lot of terms.

```
dictionary_small_scale = dict([tuple(x) for x in df.viz_words.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().\
reset_index().values])

#generate wordcloud and plot using matplotlib 
wordcloud = WordCloud()
wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies(dictionary_small_scale)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```